# Are Algebraic types just the combination of case classes and pattern matching?

Tags: type-theory, pattern-recognition, abstract-data-types

On [this page describing the precursor to the Scala language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pizza_%28programming_language%29) - the pizza language - they refer to it having both case classes and [pattern matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching) - and then imply that these taken together provide [algebraic types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type).

Is this the case? To provide algebraic types - do you combine [case classes and pattern matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29#Case_classes_and_pattern_matching)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scala provides algebraic types and pattern matching in a way that is compatible with classes, but this is not what algebraic types are – it is Scala's realisation of the concept. Technically, pattern matching is not even needed for algebraic types; it just makes them must more convenient to use. One could instead use functions the pull apart the types. Early scheme's approach to ADTs would do just this.

Comment: Thanks @Dave - could you provide a link to Early Scheme's approach to ADTs?

Comment: All I meant by the comment about early Scheme is that it didn't have pattern matching, but you could still construct ADTs.